# passing parameter for event listener

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

```
  window.addEventListener('keydown',function keydown_f(e){
    if(e.code === 'ArrowDown') {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
      // do something
      setTimeout(2000,function(){
        window.addEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
      });
    }
    else if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
      // do something
      setTimeout(2000,function(){
        window.addEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
      });
    }
  });
```

I am using above code to capture keydown event every 2 seconds. I thought it wouldn't work because when 2000ms later the event listener is added back(line 6 and line 13), it doesn't specify what parameter it is getting, it is like in first line I write

```
  window.addEventListener('keydown',function keydown_f(){  //without "e"
```

and that should trigger an error like

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

But actually the code is working, I don't understand why when the listener is added back it recognize `e` without specifying `e` as a paramter?

Comment: When you ***reference*** a function, the arguments are passed automatically, always, there's nothing magical here?

Comment: @adeneo "the arguments are passed automatically" --- this is slightly misleading. The caller passes them explicitly, it's not "automatic".

Comment: @zerkms - sure, arguments would always have to be passed by the caller to exist in the called function, so I guess you could say that the arguments are passed automatically in both named and anonymous functions, assuming they're actually passed. The real issue the OP seems to have, is to think that naming the "anonymous" function would make any difference, leaving out the `e` argument from the function would  always make `e` undefined, which is even more obvious, regardless of what the function is named, or how it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because is the context of where you set "function keydown_f", it is accessible to:

```
   if(e.code === 'ArrowDown') {
  window.removeEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
  // do something
  setTimeout(2000,function(){
    window.addEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
  });
}
else if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
  window.removeEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
  // do something
  setTimeout(2000,function(){
    window.addEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);
  });
}
```

It is within scope.

The function itself "keydown_f" takes a param --- "e". So, when you call it, lets say: window.addEventListener('keydown',keydown_f);

the "event" gets passed.

Basically, "addEventListener" grabs this: "keydown_f", and does this: "keydown_f(event)"

think of "keydown_f" as a callback, well it is a callback. "addEventListener" uses that function, and "calls it" and passes in its argument = event.